# Configure jump/bastion host using password

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have three hosts:

- my local ansible controller
- a jump/bastion host (`jump_host`) for my infrastructure
- a target host I want to run ansible tasks against (`target_host`) which is only accessible through `jump_host`

As part of my inventory file, I have the details of both `jump_host` and `target_host` as follows:

```yaml
    jump_host:
      ansible_host: "{{ jump_host_ip }}"
      ansible_port: 22
      ansible_user: root
      ansible_password: password
    target_host:
      ansible_host: "{{ target_host_ip }}"
      ansible_port: 22
      ansible_user: root
      ansible_password: password
      ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q root@{{ jump_host_ip }}"'
```

How can we configure ansible to use the password mentioned in the `jump_host` settings from the inventory file instead of using any additional configurations from `~/.ssh/config file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to provide the password for the jump host as part of the `ProxyCommand`.

So, I ended up doing the following:

```yaml
# Generate SSH keys on the controller

- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  tasks:
    - name: Generate the localhost ssh keys
      community.crypto.openssh_keypair:
        path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        force: no

# Copy the host keys of Ansible host into the jump_host .ssh/authorized_keys file
# to ensure that no password is prompted while logging into jump_host

- hosts: jump_host
  become: false
  tasks:
    - name: make sure public key exists on target for user
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa') }}"
        state: present
```